# keyframe animation in jquery not working

Tags: jquery

Can anyone tell me why keyframe animation is not working in jquery.I have searched a lot of examples but not getting whats wrong.In some codes i have seen the keys (for example 0%,50% etc) in quotes and in some other its not.Which one is correct because both are not working. I have commented the keyframe animation part.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function(){                                               


            $.keyframe.define([{
                name: 'myfirst',
                '0%':   {'top':'-20px'},
                '50%':   {'top':'20px'},
                //'50%': {'top':$("img[name=registrationimg]").innerHeight() + "20px"},
                '100%': {'top':$("img[name=registrationimg]").innerHeight() }
            }]);

            $("img[name=registrationimg]").playKeyframe({
                name: 'myfirst',
                duration: 2000
            });


        });

    </script>
```

HTML :

```
<div id="header">           
        <h1>USER REGISTRATION</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="imagediv">
        <img name="registrationimg" src="registration.jpg"/>
    </div>
    <div id="registrationdiv"><center>      
    <form name="registrationform"  onsubmit="submitform()">
        <table id="registrationtable" cellspacing="10">
            <tr><td>Email <font color="red">*</font> : </td><td><input type="email" name="email" placeholder="vallabh@harbingergroup.com"></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Password <font color="red">*</font> : </td><td><input type="password"></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Confirm Password <font color="red">*</font> : </td><td><input type="password" name="repassword"></td></tr>
            <tr><td>First Name <font color="red">*</font> : </td><td><input type="text" placeholder="Vallabh" name="firstname"></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Last Name : </td><td><input type="text"></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Address : </td><td><input type="text"></td></tr>
            <tr><td>City : </td><td><input type="text" ></td></tr>
            <tr><td>State : </td><td><input type="text" ></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Country : <font color="red">*</font></td><td><input type="text" placeholder="India" name="country"></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Phone : </td><td><input type="tel" ></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Zipcode : </td><td><input type="number" ></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Date of Birth <font color="red">*</font> : </td><td><input type="date" name="dob"></td></tr>
            <tr><td colspan="2">By submitting, I agree that all information entered was done accurately & truthfully.</td></tr>
            <tr><td>I accept <input type="checkbox" name="accept" id="iaccept"></td></tr>
            <tr><td><input type="submit" name="Submit"></td><td><input type="reset" name="Reset"></td></tr>
        </table>
    </form></center>
    </div>
```

Comment: What it should do and isn't doing? In this fiddle it appears to work: http://jsfiddle.net/4b5tyzhk/

Comment: I have commented out the code that was not working.Try it now

Comment: Ok, just for me to understand, you want to achieve a *bounce* effect?